# In Meteor, How do I access the Request Object?

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor 0.5.0 on windows. So far, I haven't had many issues getting my app up and running. My app will take requests from external sites, and they will send the information required through the querystring.

I looked at this: [How do I access Request Parameters in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799079/how-do-i-access-request-parameters-in-meteor), but it just loaded to a blank screen when I changed "foo" to the root. I still need the page to load like normal.

How can I access the Request Object in meteor? I would like to look at the server_variables as well as the querystring.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the other post is good but needs 1 more command and needs to remove 2 commands to make it work like you like.

```
SomeCollection = new Collection("...")
fibers = __meteor_bootstrap__.require("fibers");
connect = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('connect')
app = __meteor_bootstrap__.app

router = connect.middleware.router (route) ->
  route.get '/', (req, res,next) ->
    Fiber () ->
      SomeCollection.insert(...)
    .run()
    next()
app.use(router)
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: As of Meteor 0.6.0 `__meteor_bootstrap__.require();` is replaced with `Npm.require();`