# How to serve HTTP requests over meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, meteor, http-live-streaming

I am creating a live streaming application using meteor. Currently I have a need to create a live transcoding option, so I am trying to integrate this node.js module with our meteor application: https://github.com/mifi/hls-vod. However, the way it works is that you actually call the app.get(hls/) from your HTML5 video tag's src. I am wondering if there is a way to expect the call to this get using meteor. Since I can't integrate express with meteor I am having some trouble doing this. I am wondering if there is a way to have meteor receive HTTP requests and send back data as per the node module.

Comment: Did you have a look at the Meteor.http API?

Comment: Yes I did, but that's for making http calls, not for receiving requests, so it is only half of what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post has been updated

To server http requests over meteor you need a router. I would recommend ironRouter. There was meteor router but Tom Coleman also built ironRouter.

You can use something like this:

```
Router.map(function () {


this.route('serverFile', {
    path: '/pathonserver',

    action: function () {
      console.log(this.params); //Contains params

      this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      this.response.end('hello from server');
    }
  });
});
```

Hopefully that should get the route working similar to the express router.

Comment: That looks like almost exactly what I need! My only issue is that meteorite is not supported for Windows at the moment. Is there another alternative that I could use for this then?

Comment: Yes you could get the `app` exposed. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914885/how-to-get-current-user-in-custom-route

Answer (score 4):

Meteor Router is now deprecated for [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).

See [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing) for Server Side Routing with Iron Router

Answer (score 0):

You directly use the underlying [webapp](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html) as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048610/meteor-webapp-middleware-passing-params)
or [flow-router](https://github.com/veliovgroup/flow-router)
or [picker](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/picker) for SSR routes.