# Meteor Iron Router How to get POST data

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I am trying to pass POST data to an Iron Router route from outside meteor but it doesn't work. The request body is empty.

I have tried outputting the request body to check if the data were present, but it's just empty.

```
Router.route('/api/gatewaysusers', function() {
        body = this.request.body;
        console.log(this.request)
        // this.response.write(body);
        this.response.end("Call served");


}, {where: 'server'})
```

Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access Request Parameters in Meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799079/how-do-i-access-request-parameters-in-meteor)

Comment: @ChristianFritz it's not a duplicate. The code here is totally fine and the problem is on `iron-router` side.

Comment: For anyone arriving from Google who wants to use the above code with arrow functions, you don't need to get `request` and `response` from `this`. They are also passed to the callback. The first line can be rewritten as `Router.route('/api/gatewaysusers', (request, response) => {`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `request.body` is empty because `iron-router` lacks middleware responsible for extracting url-encoded data. This is a **BUG**, which will be hopefully solved in later versions. For now you can just add:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

somewhere on your server and it should work fine. Look [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1003) for more details.

Comment: This is working, Thank you. Now i can get the body using this.request.body.

Comment: It seems to be fixed by the way, `this.request.body` now has all the data expected without this extra call.

Comment: @romaroma Do you know precisely in which version of IR it was solved?

Comment: @apendua sorry, don't know it for sure. We used iron:router@1.0.12 in our recent project.